# Apache2 Cross-Origin Request Blocked while headers are set

Tags: apache-2.2, firefox, cross-domain, font

My website uses CDN and while everything is fine on Chrome in Firefox I'm getting the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://static.website.com/wp-content/themes/themename/fonts/font-name.woff. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

When I've checked my website .htaccess file I've noticed that header is open to * when requesting this kind of files (fonts)

Here is what I have set:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas what else needs to be done to allowed fonts to serve from CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution eventually.

We had to set CORS on our bucket (we use Amazon S3) since the files served to the CDN from it and not directly from the website.

[Here is some info on how to do it](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)